# C#. Does shortening identifier names increase overall run-time performance of an application?

Tags: c#, performance, runtime, obfuscation

Shortening identifier names makes the resulting executable smaller in size since MSIL code includes all these names except local variable ones. Does it affect executing the code in .NET runtime in a good way in terms of performance, at least in theory? Native machine code doesn't include all those names but it interoperates with .NET runtime. So I wonder if it makes sense to obfuscate (namely shorten identifier names) the MSIL code in order to increase the run-time performance of the application at least a little.

I was surprised by this statement: "Dotfuscator improves run-time performance. By removing unneeded program elements and renaming identifiers to small names, Dotfuscator can actually speed up programs." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227226.aspx

Comment: As to the statement: "Dotfuscator improves run-time performance. By removing unneeded program elements and renaming identifiers to small names, Dotfuscator can actually speed up programs."  It is probably true if "unneeded program elements" are removed -- it then makes the resulting code smaller and more compact, resulting in a performance gain.  However, I doubt that this performance gain will amount to much -- since you are unlikely going to have a lot of program elements in your program that is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

The identifier names get discarded by the compiler/jitter, so this will not make any difference.

Comment: Does the statement related to Dotfuscator (I added it to my original post) make sense?

Comment: @bsnote - The part about removing unneeded program elements might (reducing memory consumption, hence increasing speed).

Comment: @Oded, well meta data is still kept after jitting for use in reflection.  So there is a memory cost here -- and performance implications if memory usage spill out to more RAM pages.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you run an application, the MSIL is compiled to machine code for that platform - after that the machine code is executed.  So theoretically, I would think the 1st time compile MIGHT be affected, but the final machine code execution time which doesn't use those names won't change a whit after the machine compilation is done.